# How do I utilise all the cores for nmake?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, multicore, nmake

I just got a new quad core computer and noticed that nmake is only using 1 process.

I used to use make which had the switch -j4 for launching 4 processes.  What is the nmake equivalent?

[edit]
Based on the information below I have been able to add a command to my qmake project file:

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MP

Which effectively did it for me.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afyyse50(VS.71).aspx), there's no such option for `nmake`.

You can however make the compiler build multiple files in parallel by using the `/MP` option with the VC++ command line compiler and passing multiple files at the same time:

```
> cl /MP a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
```

However note that most Makefiles don't call the compiler like this - they usual invoke the compiler separate for each individual source file, which would prevent the `/MP` option from doing anything useful.

Comment: Only not .o, but .obj. VC++ compilers generates .obj, GCC - .o, AFAIK

Comment: A convenient way to use this flag is to let cl.exe retrieve it from the "CL" environment variable. Set it in your system properties or type it on the command line: "set CL= /MP"

Answer (score 58):

Another generic, non-Qt-related way to tell `nmake` to use all the cores is to set environmental variable `CL` to `/MP`:

```
set CL=/MP
nmake
```

will use all the CPU cores.

Comment: As I understand it this only helps if multiple files are compiled using the same command.

Comment: @Zitrax: you are correct. Typically, you compile a project (bunch of files) so it works.

Comment: The project I looked at compile a few hundred files, but each one uses a separate cl command, like `cl a.cpp, cl b.cpp, cl c.cpp, ...` So I wanted to point out that it does not seem to help in such situation with nmake unless the build system is rewritten into supplying several files to each cl command like `cl a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp ...`.

Comment: @Zitrax: Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/batch-mode-rules?view=vs-2017 is relevant? I have not tried it myself.

Comment: That misleading hint to use `set CL=/MP` should really be dismissed more clearly.
It has caused quite some extra work needlessly.

Comment: @dvo: the "misleading hint" worked great for me for many years on many different projects, especially those I just to want to build and be done with without modifying the supplied project files. If you've discovered a problem, it would be much more useful if you elaborated on it to warn others rather than just complain "something didn't work".

Answer (score 40):

QT has a tool for this:
http://download.qt.io/official_releases/jom/

They also use it per default in Qt creator.

Comment: Precompiled jom binaries are here: ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/jom/

Comment: The link is dead and this is an `nmake` question; not a QT question. Perhaps you can explain things a bit more.

Comment: @jww this link was alive. 9 year ago at least (and updates for it in more recent connents)
also. Have you seen tag "qt" and "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS" in question? 
also there was no support for using multiple cores in nmake 9 years ago...

so there are no reason downvote the answer.

Comment: @jww: jom is a drop-in nmake replacement, it has no dependency on Qt.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Or so I thought... While jom works for NMake files generated by QMake, it does not work for NMake file generated by CMake; it complains about an invalid NMake format file. So in that case, it is not a drop-in replacement. Edit: It works when using the CMake generator "NMake Makefiles JOM".

Comment: if you're using CMake you should use the Ninja generator instead of nmake or jom, it will be much faster especially for incremental rebuilds @jmk

Answer (score 6):

[Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/) claims to be able to run nmake builds on multiple cores / multiple machines. I don't have any experience of it.

Comment: It's very simple actually and works great. This is a good reference: http://xoreax.helpserve.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=171

Comment: Yep! I worked on an app. that took about 1h 20min. to compile in full. With Incredibuild and about 10 multi-processor machines, the same app. compiled in 5 min. Quite impressive improvement if you ask me!

Comment: The link to the reference on how to accelerate nMake using IncrediBuild has changed to [link](http://xoreax.helpserve.com/staff/Knowledgebase/Article/Edit/105).           Disclaimer - the writer of this comment works at IncrediBuild

Comment: @Dori - The link is behind a login. Can you provide a link that does not require us to buy the product or join the company or one of its programs?

Comment: @jww I'm very sorry, but you'll require to register in order to receive a version of IncrediBuild (registering in order to receive a product link is a customary practice...). Once registered you'll get a 30 days trial license of the product which will allow you to distribute compilation tasks across additional cores in your network (thus increasing the amount of cores participating in your build to up to 5 machines of 8 cores each). Once the trial period is over you'll still be able to use IncrediBuild on your local machine free of charge :)  Disclaimer - the writer works at IncrediBuild

Answer (score 6):

The [CMake 2.8.1 RC1](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-February/035018.html), as for the time of writing this it's ready to try, does bring new generator for NMake which is called [NMake Makefiles JOM](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-February/035021.html) and it generates NMake with specific settings for jom, which is the drop in replacement of NMake. Thus, it gives multi-processing enabled building using NMake.

Answer (score 2):

Quick googling gives: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx

Comment: that's parallel compilation of multiple .cpp files in the same invocation of the compiler - not parallel building of multiple 'make' targets

Comment: It's very interesting, how to switch on this switch in VS2008! I can't find it

Comment: it's not an "nmake" option, it's a "c1" option (i.e. for use with the command line compiler)

Comment: Yeap, cl.exe, so it must be possible to use in Visual Studio, as far as it calls it directly, I guess, not using nmake. Or I'm not right?

Comment: Didn't Visual Studion use that switch by default? I remember it batch compiling files already.

Comment: Yes the IDE will use it by default, it just starts two instances of cl - but you can't use it with nmake.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work for normal makefiles, but there is a setting in Visual Studio 2005 that lets you build more than one .vcproj file at the same time (provided one isn't dependent on the other).  Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> **X** maximum number of parallel project builds.

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite the same, but if you use `cmake`, you can export solution (e.g. using generator "Visual Studio 14 2015" instead of "NMake Makefiles").

In this case it's possible to build exported solution using `msbuild` tool which allows you to parallelize building process with `/maxcpucount` command line switch.