# Qt Creator Windows 10 - "Use jom instead of nmake" not working

Tags: parallel-processing, compilation, cmake, qt-creator, nmake

I am using Qt version 5.5.1 (but with the 5.6.1 GUI), I am compiling with MSVC++ Compiler 10.0, and I have checked the "Use jom instead of nmake" option in the Options -> Build & Run -> General menu. I am using the latest version of cmake, and the Options -> Build & Run - > Kits -> CMake generator is set to "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles". To be honest, I do not know what that last option does, it is just the default.

I am building and running through the QT creator IDE.

If I add -j to the "tool arguments" in Projects -> Build&Run -> Build Steps, then when I try to compile I get the error:

```
NMAKE:-1: error: U1065: invalid option 'j'
```

However, I have "Use jom instead of nmake" selected so it should use jom and accept this argument, shouldn't it?

Have I missed out a step?

I cannot find any instructions on how to do this, and the only tutorials I can find to compile using jom are compiling through the command line, which I do not want to do.

*edit: This is a different question from [How do I utilise all the cores for nmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601970/how-do-i-utilise-all-the-cores-for-nmake) as this question is specifically asking why the Jom solution (suggested as an answer in that question) is not working with my set up.*

*edit 2: I think I may have found out why. [This bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-16295) suggests that you need to use the  `"CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM"` option in the kits -> cmake generator options.This is only supported with QtCreator 4.2.1 and above. However, I have this and it still does not work. I now get the error:*

```
C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.8\Modules\CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51: error: The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program. It fails with the following output: Change Dir: C:/GIT/CorteX/build/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

Comment: @usr1234567 I've explained why this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nmake file can be natively used by Jom, thus the cmake generator doesn't not need to be changed from the default nmake generator in the build configuration. The cmake generator is what converts your cmake to your native build system format (e.g. make, or nmake).

(i.e. Projects > Manage Kits ... > Build & Runs > Kits. choose your kit. I have my Cmake generator: set to "CodeBlocks - Nmake Makefiles, Platform: , Toolset: " ).

The only change you then need is to add a custom build step to run jom.exe and disable the default build step, as in [Qtcreator JOM setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpSWX.png).

N.b. jom.exe must be in your PATH variable for QtCreator to find it.

Answer (score 0):

jom requires that -j , where you set the number of processes, e.g. `jom -j4`. You can't use just `-j` without a count.